# How to Sum from Content in File with Fstream

Tags: c++

i Have this struct

```
typedef struct billing
{
    char noKom[50], paket[50];
    int biaya;
    char tglHabis[100];
    char tglSekarang[100];
} billing;
```

and this to call

```
baca.open("billing.dat", ios::binary);
while(baca.read((char *) &bil,sizeof(bil)))
{
    if(strcmp(tanggal_sekarang,bil.tglSekarang)==0) {
        cout<<"\t\t\t---------------------------";
        cout << "\n\t\t\tKomputer: " <<bil.noKom;
        cout << "\n\t\t\tPaket: " << bil.paket;
        cout << "\n\t\t\tBiaya: " << bil.biaya;
        cout << "\n\t\t\ttglHabis: " << bil.tglHabis;
        cout<<"\n\t\t\t---------------------------";
        cout<<endl;
    } else {
        cout<<"tidak ada hari ini"<<endl;
    }
}
```

i need to sum all content of bil.biaya
how the method?

Comment: Sum all `bil` objects read, or just the ones with the specified `tanggal_sekarang`?

Comment: only values from bil.biaya